# Donut tutorial: Source Objects used for sprinkle particles is showing up in render. How do I hide them? Did I mess up my collections?

Tags: particles, collections, outliner

Blender 2.92.0

Part 2 level 2 of the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc

Already looking at this it seems I've messed up the collections of the sprinkles somehow? I see double of sprinkles in the Outliner, one set at the very bottom in no collection and one in a collection (they are all still linked together) - I don't know how I managed that. In the tutorial he only had the whole set of sprinkle objects in one collection - is this related to my render problem and if so how do I go on about making it look the same again without messing up the materials I have set up and such?

Main issue is I need help hiding the source objects of the sprinkles so they don't end up in the final render - I do recall there was some setting or hotkeys on how to change the visibility of the objects for the viewport and renders respectively but I can't find how to easily toggle it.

Thank you in advance!

My settings:[image]

My render:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncheck the checkbox next to your sprinkles collection circled in red, it will hide the objects in the collection, while still showing the particles on the donut.

[image: Outliner checkbox]

Comment: Halfway there. That hid the Sphere. Which is the only one that is exclusively in the collection. https://i.imgur.com/KWSeNsn.png

How do I fix my collection organization?

Comment: I figured out a solution, I right clicked the sprinkle objects inside the collection and chose "Unlink" (not the sphere) then moved the sprinkle objects that were outside the collection into it! 

I don't know what Unlink means or how I got here in the first place, I would actually appreciate if anyone can explain to me what I did wrong since I want to understand Blender more :) thanks for your help